# How do you apply a filter to JavaFX using CSS?

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

I've been fiddling with JavaFX and the stylesheets incorporation and was trying to figure out a way to manipulate the images a bit. I know there's `filter` in CSS, but what about JavaFX -fx?

I have the following:

```
.root {
    -fx-background-image: url("background.jpg");
    -fx-background-size: cover;
    // -fx-filter: contrast(200%)
}
```

Which is imported with:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(Class.class.getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Is there a way to do this, or is there a better alternative to Java GUI with more control? Normal filter: contrast(200%) does not work with JavaFX it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to do this without CSS. JavaFX actually has effects built in that you can use. For example, for lighting, you can use

```
import javafx.scene.effect.Light;
import javafx.scene.effect.Lighting;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
```

And then:

```
    Light.Distant light = new Light.Distant();

    Lighting lighting = new Lighting(light);
    lighting.setSurfaceScale(5.0);
```

Set up azimuth:

```
DoubleProperty azimuth = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
azimuth.bind(value);
```

From there, you can apply it on any object:

```
light.setAzimuth(azimuth.get());
lighting.setLight(light);
sampletext.setEffect(lighting);
```

Alter the "value" the azimuth is bound to and it should change the lighting.

Referenced:
http://zetcode.com/gui/javafx/effects/